# Using a running total for calculator

Tags: java, android, calculator, cumulative-sum

I made a calculator on android. I get results for only two numbers (1+1), but I would like to be able to do more then one calculation at a time instead of hitting enter every time I need a new answer (1+1-2).

Something like this: 2 + 2 (new operator pressed) 4 + 3 (equals is pressed) 7

But I'm not sure how to implement this on my code.

This is the button code for every operator:

```
btnPlus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            perform();
            operation = "+";
        }
    }); // end btnPlus
```

This is my calculation method:

```
private void calculate() {

    if (operation == null) {
        numberInput.setText(null);

    } else if (operation.equals("+")){
        numResult = (secondNum + firstNum);
        numberInput.setText(String.valueOf(numResult));

    } else if (operation.equals("-")) {
        numResult = (secondNum - firstNum);
        numberInput.setText(String.valueOf(numResult));

    } else if (operation.equals("/")) {
        numResult = (secondNum / firstNum);
        numberInput.setText(String.valueOf(numResult));

    } else if (operation.equals("*")) {
        numResult = (secondNum * firstNum);
        numberInput.setText(String.valueOf(numResult));
    } // end if statement

}
```

Also, perform if needed:

```
private void perform() {
    str = "";
    secondNum = firstNum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick way to solve your problem given your current code is to use textChangeListener/TextWatcher(assuming you have an **EditText** or **TextView**) to detect every time an operator is entered then call the operate function. It would look something like this.

```
myEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
       int count, int after) {
    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
      int before, int count) {
      // if 2nd operator is detected
      // call calculate
      // append 2nd operator
    }
```

});

Answer (score 0):

You could do as i suggested in the comment, and just make a list for every operation, and then calculate it every time the current data changes (there may be difffrent ways to "know" if some of the result is final depending on how you can delete from the app.

SOmething like this is what i would do, and then just everytime a button is pressed call the logic for adding the input, and then calculate it and write it out

```
public class Calc {

    private List<String> inputs = new ArrayList<>();

    public String calculate(List<String> input){
        String result = "";
        for(String current : input){
            switch (current) {
                case "(":
                    // do stuff
                case "+":
                    //do stuff
                default:
                    // do stuff
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    btnPlus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // add to list, and call calculate
        }
    }); // end btnPlus
}
```